# Docker build argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How does one pass arguments into a dockerfile?

Lets say I have the dockerfile:

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Karl Morrison

sudo do-something-here myVarHere
```

I would want to build the file as so for example:

```
docker build basickarl/my-image-example /directory/of/my/dockerfile "my string to be passed to myVarHere here!"
```

Answer (score 7):

Docker has `ARG` that you can use here

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Karl Morrison

ARG myVarHere

RUN do-something-here myVarHere
```

And then build using `--build-arg`:

```
docker build --build-arg myVarHere=value
```

Comment: For those having trouble with build args, the above is largely correct, however the args are accessed as environment variables in the RUN commands.  You can see the documentation on this [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).  The RUN command above would then be: `RUN do-something-here $myVarHere`

Comment: should the build file line  "RUN do-something-here myVarHere" actually be "RUN do-something-here ${myVarHere}"  ?

Answer (score 2):

We've had a similar requirement and came up with a relatively simple script that does exactly that:

We create a file called `dockerfile_template` in which we use variables just like you describe. The script takes that file, performs string substitutions and copies it to `dockerfile` (no _template) before calling `docker build dockerfile`.

Works pretty good. Also very extensible for future requirements.

**Update**:

Scrap that. Use `build-arg` ([here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/))